# How to make buttons link within a framework

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, zurb-foundation

ok, so basically i am trying to link a webpage from a framework's button.

`<a href="snipplr.com/placeholder" class="button expand secondary text-left" > <h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2></a>`

however, this redirects to 
`example.com/snipplr.com/placeholder`, 
intended link wanted is 
`snipplr.com/placeholder` which is not the case. I am also not intending to use HTML's button which has been the suggested solution all over other questions

I am currently using the Foundation Framework, relatable to Bootstrap, Thank you for reading and offering help, Not going to submit quick replies as i will be heading off and be back in 6 hrs.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a protocol to the link

```
<a href="//snipplr.com/placeholder"....
```

or

```
<a href="https://snipplr.com/placeholder"...
```

or

```
<a href="http://snipplr.com/placeholder"....
```

Comment: Oh my, thanks for the quick reply, was about the leave, that helped, Thanks.